# How to change raphael element picture

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have an element with a picture.

```
el = r.image("images/pic1.png", x, y, w, h);
```

How to change it's picture later when I need it?
Updating src like that wont't help:

```
el.attr({src: "images/pic2.png"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in this thread: [How to update the source of an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068408/how-to-update-the-source-of-an-image)

Answer by sosuke worked best for me:

```
function setImgSrc(targetImg, newSrc) {
    if (targetImg.node.src) {
        targetImg.node.src = newSrc;
    } else {
        targetImg.node.href.baseVal = newSrc;
    }
}
```